# How to keep duplicate spring bean in container. [ConflictingBeanDefinitionException]

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, inversion-of-control

I am working on an application which uses some third java libraries which are build on top of core spring framework.
Now when my application uses these libraries I am getting ConflictingBeanDefinitionException because two libraries have the same bean name.
Now as these libraries are external I cannot change the bean name. Is there a way by which in my application I can use both the beans in same container?

```
 @Component
    class ApplicationLogic {

    @Autowire FetcherAndResolver fetchFromLibraryA;
    @Autowire FetcherAndResolver fetchFromLibraryB;  //Because both bean names are same here comes the exception.
}
```

Comment: tagging, I am also looking for an answer. similar situation

Comment: how does `FetcherAndResolver` from those libs end up in your context? auto-configuration? scanning? etc

Comment: @Eugene yes auto configuration

Answer (score 1):

I think this would require a bit of a hack.

First of all, structure your packages in a way so that external beans are not added automatically.

So, if external class is located in package `a.b`. Then you have to move your own classes in either `a.c` or `a.b.c`. THis will ensure that you are in control of how beans are initialized.

Once this is done, you can add a `@Configuration` class where you can create Beans of both type:

```java
@Configuration
public class ExternalBeanConfiguration {

   @Bean("internal-resolver" )
   public FetcherAndResolver internalResolver() {
       return new FetcherAndResolver();
   }

   @Bean("external-resolver" )
   public a.b.c.FetcherAndResolver externalResolver() {
       return new a.b.c.FetcherAndResolver();
   }

}
```

I am assuming that `FetcherAndResolver` is a class rather than an interface. If it is an interface, it is easier to do it as you won't have to use fully-qualified name for classes.

Then you can simply autowire with qualifiers.

```java
@Component
public class SomeComponent {

    @Qualifier( "internal-resolver" )
    FetcherAndResolver internalResolver;

    @Qualifier( "external-resolver" )
    FetcherAndResolver externalResolver;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

First component from third java libraries:

```
package com.example.component1;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class MyComponent {
    public String makeSomeWork() {
        return "Component 1";
    }
}
```

Second component from third java libraries:

```
package com.example.component2;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class MyComponent {
    public String makeSomeWork() {
        return "Component 2";
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
package com.example.controller;

import com.example.component1.MyComponent;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class MyController {

    @Autowired
    private MyComponent myComponent;

    @Autowired
    private com.example.component2.MyComponent myComponent2;

    @RequestMapping("/components")
    public String getComponents() {
        return myComponent.makeSomeWork() + "_" + myComponent2.makeSomeWork();
    }
}
```

Comment: This will give [ConflictingBeanDefinitionException] as both the bean names are same [MyComponent]  @Denis Rodin